# PDO: Fetch and FetchAll on the same Statement

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

Hi I have the following code which selects some results from a table that I have. I haven't included the SQL/Table structure as I know the SQL statement operates as expected.

My problem is when wanting to "recycle" a prepared statement i.e. I want to just `fetch` the first result and then `fetchAll` of the results. When I `fetchAll`, the result set only contains one result (the last result), but there should be two results.

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare(*SQL STATEMENT*);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS| PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,'MyClass');
    $oneResult = $stmt->fetch();
    echo $oneResult->get_Name();

    $allResults = $stmt->fetchAll;
    foreach($allResults as $row){
        echo $row->getField_Name();
   }
```

Is it possible to use a `fetchAll` and `fetch` in succession without preparing a new statement?

Comment: Why can't you just fetch all the results, then use the first element of that array? The behaviour you've described is actually beneficial in most cases.

Comment: Why don't you use fetchall, and then echo the first result by specifying that you want the first result to be echo'd?

Comment: @raina77ow thanks for the help, this resolved my problem. Please put this as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

Just use fetchall and then use the resulting array to get your first and then to iterate:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare(*SQL STATEMENT*);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS| PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,'MyClass');
$allResults = $stmt->fetchAll;
$oneResult = each($allResults);
echo $oneResult->get_Name();
foreach($allResults as $row){
    echo $row->getField_Name();
}
```